# PHP expressions fail when changing from ereg to preg_match

Tags: php, regex, pcre, posix-ere

I have a class that uses PHP's `ereg()` which is deprecated.
Looking on PHP.net I thought I could just get away and change to `preg_match()`

But I get errors with the regular expressions or they fail!!

Here are two examples:

```
function input_login() {
    if (ereg("[^-_@\.A-Za-z0-9]", $input_value)) { // WORKS
    // if (preg_match("[^-_@\.A-Za-z0-9]", $input_value)) { // FAILS
        echo "is NOT alphanumeric with characters - _ @ . allowed";
    }
}

// validate email
function validate_email($email) {
    // return eregi("^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $email); // FAILS
}
```

Comment: For the validate_email function try using the filter_var('email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the delimiters:

```
if (preg_match("/[^-_@.A-Za-z0-9]/", $input_value))
```

Also, the dot doesn't need to be escaped inside a character class.

For your validation function, you need to make the regex case-insensitive by using the `i` modifier:

```
return preg_match('/^[_.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i', $email)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't suppress the suspicion anymore that people simply don't like my `+@example.org` email address (I changed the right part only). It is an absolutely normal address, it's valid, short and easy to type. Simply people don't like it! One cannot register on *any* page using that mail.

So, why don't be nice and use PHPs Filter extension to verify the mail or to use a PCRE, which definitely allows all valid emails in use (excluding only the @[] ones):

```
/^[^@]+@(?:[^.]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/
```

Thanks for saving my email, it's a dieing species!

Answer (score 0):

try `preg_match("/[^-_@\.A-Za-z0-9]/", $input_value)`